# Can a charged particle be retrieved from beyond the event horizon?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, black-holes, event-horizon

So I read [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420582/magnet-pulling-repelling-another-magnet-beyond-the-event-horizon), which is similar, but not the same. My question involves a standard, non-charged, non-rotating Schwartzchild black hole.

If a charged particle, (let's use an electron) passes into the event horizon of a black hole, secant to the horizon, and an opposite charge of large magnitude, was placed outside the event horizon, but by the path of the electron, could the electron be pulled out from the event horizon? If so, what are the limits to how close the electron can approach the singularity and the charge of the outside object?

Answer (score -3):

The timespace there is curved. There is no path out. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please provide the reasoning for your answer, and cite relevant evidence.