# Visualizing vector fields lines in Kerr

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I want to visualise an **test** EM field in Kerr spacetime (I want to plot the integral field lines). The field is a **test** field in the sense, that it doesn't change the background (metric).

Could anyone point me to some more technical literature or some Mathematica/python code that would help me?

What I thought I would do:
I have the field $F^{\alpha \beta}$ in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates. I then took the *ZAMO* tetrad (observer family) $e^\alpha_a$ with $e^\mu_0 = u^\mu$ is the for velocity normalized to $$u_\alpha u^\alpha = -1.$$ I then projected the EM tensor onto the tetrad
$$
F^{\alpha \beta} e_\alpha^a e_\beta^a = F^{ab}
$$
and from this I took the standard definition of electric field
$$
E^\alpha = -\frac{1}{2} F^{\alpha \beta }u_\beta \implies E^a = -\frac{1}{2} F^{a0} 
$$
So now I have the electric field with respects to the *ZAMO* tetrad.

But how do i visualize this? The tetrad is still expressed in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates (which are like spheriodial coordinates). Do I have to transform into Kerr-Schild coordinates which reduce to cartesian (minkowski) in the flat-spacetime limit?

I hope it's obvious from the context, but I used Greek letters $\alpha \beta$ to denote the indices with respect to coordinates and Latin letters $ab$ to denote indices with respect to tetrad.

For example I would like to plot something like figure 2 and figure 3 in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0610841.pdf).

Edit: The question can also be reduced to - do I always need to transform to cartesian like coordinates when plotting fields on curved background.

Comment: I am speaking only of the visualization aspects here - I have been plotting geodesics in the Kerr metric for some time now.  Firstly the easy part, I just use the conversion on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates.  For the visualization, I use something like "gnuplot -p -e "set style data vector; splot 'vector_fields.data' using 1:2:3:4:5:6" where the format is x,y,z,dx,dy,dz, if that helps.

Comment: Do you mean the equations for $x,y,z$? Aren't those only for the case $M\to 0$?

Comment: On closer inspection, the lower case "m" is not defined anywhere.  If they _really_ mean "M", then that statement (M -> 0) is nonsense since "a" is defined as J/M, where M _is_ the mass.  Looks like a bit of a mess TBH, but I have always used that transformation for non-zero "M"!  I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: OK I've just checked Visser's "The Kerr Spacetime", https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622.  Looks like the wiki page has garbled equations 59 with 60-62, but the (M -> 0) part is only applicable to the _derivation_ of the coordinate transformation.  I think this is the right conclusion, what do you think? (EDIT haha that is exactly the reference quoted in the wiki page!)

Comment: OK, now I see what you were asking: x, y, z are the coordinates, and dx, dy, dz are the field components.  My other comments are still valid though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nataa a asked: *"I want to visualise an test EM field in Kerr spacetime [...] But how do i visualize this? [...] Could anyone point me to some more technical literature or some Mathematica/python code that would help me?"*

The Mathematica code for the $\rm \{\lambda,z\}$-plot

[image: magnetic and electric field lines]

is at [kerr.newman.yukterez.net](http://kerr.newman.yukterez.net) at *17) streamplot*, also see [doi:10.1103/physreva.36.5118](https://sci-hub.st/https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.36.5118)

For the vertical and horizontal magnetic and electric field lines we have

$\rm M_z=Q \ Im[(z-ia)/\sigma] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ M_{\lambda}=Q \ Im[\lambda/\sigma]$

$\rm E_z=Q \ Re[(z-ia)/\sigma] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ E_{\lambda}=Q \ Re[\lambda/\sigma]$

$\rm \sigma=[\lambda^2+(z-ia)^2]^{3/2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \lambda=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

In a streamplot you'd plot $\rm \{M_z, M_{\lambda}\}$ as vector, and in a contourplot its magnitude.