# How do Magnetically charged black holes behave

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, magnetic-monopoles

The existence of Magnetic monopoles has not been proven or disproven.
There are equartions for Charge black holes, There are equations for Rotating black holes, but are there equations for Magnetically charged black holes?

Comment: [Magnetically charged black hole](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1253/1/012008/pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Reissner Nordström and Kerr Newman metrics can be extended by a term for a magnetic monople which is generally viewed as unphysical, but the solution exists nevertheless, see [here](https://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kerr-Newman_metric) at *magnetic charge W* (the original site scholarpedia seems to be down at the moment, therefore here the [archive](https://archive.ph/SFJgB#selection-25109.4-25111.1) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1747) another paper about the subject).

Since a rotating electric charge also produces a magnetic field, a regular Kerr Newman black hole has a magnetic dipole though, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/757551/24093).