# Electric Flux Density - Ring Charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

A ring placed along $y^{2}$ + $z^{2}$ = 4, x = 0 carries a uniform charge of 5 $\mu$C/m. Find D at P(3,0,0)

Should I be using Gauss's Law to solve this problem? I was considering using a spherical Gaussian Surface, and then using the formula D = $\epsilon_0 $E to find D, but I'm not sure how to set up my integral.

Comment: It's solved here for all (x,y,z).  The correct approach for the scope of your problem should involve trig, Coulombs law, and some intuition.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9830/tension-in-a-curved-charged-wire-electrostatic-force-does-wire-thickness-mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Gauss' law. Coulomb's law will do the trick here along with some calculus.