# Why is the electric field at the edge of a uniformly charged disk infinite?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

Consider a nonconducting disk with charge density $\sigma$ and radius $R$.

I already came across these two posts

[Infinite field but finite potential Is it possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476229/infinite-field-but-finite-potential-is-it-possible)

[Is the electric field at the edge of a uniformly charged disk infinite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40919/is-the-electric-field-at-the-edge-of-a-uniformly-charged-disk-infinite)

but the answers don't satisfy me. The answer to the first one lacks rigor while the answer to the second one is a bit too sophisticated for me with unknown terms and I am also in search for the answers to the questions asked in the first link:

1. Why is the potential at the edge of a charged ring infinite but is finite at the edge of a charged disk? it makes little sense to me physically but I suspect there could be some mathematical artifact of sorts to explain this.
2. Why is the electric field infinite at the edge of the ring and the disc? I have tried to do some integrations by trying to find the potential at a point on the infinitely extended diameter of the disk with a view to differentiate it at the edge for the field but I couldn't complete it. I look for an answer backed by some maths that is more accessible to me.

Comment: are you assuming "uniformly" distributed point charges (so there will be gaps if you zoom in enough) or an actual spread charge

Comment: The downvotes on your post are likely because of the general lack of effort in its presentation in your first version. Please have a look at my edit - consistent punctuation, proper use of paragraphs and formatting and attention to orthography (e.g. writing "don't", not "dont") can do a lot to make people engage with your question.