# Electric field at surface of uniformly charged bodies

Tags: electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

If we have any simple object like sheet,rod or sphere with uniform charge at them, is electric field at surface always finite?

For sphere I read that it is finite because as test approaches the surface the area patch which can cause infinite field at a point is also getting smaller hence charge on patch is also getting smaller.
So it is applicable for all case and if not why not?

Comment: Related: [Electric field on rim of uniformly charged disk](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/536983/electric-field-on-rim-of-uniformly-charged-disk)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the field of an infinite sheet of charge (with charge density $\sigma$), the field is:

$$ \vec E(x) = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} \frac{\vec x}{|x|} $$

It's uniform. At a distance $x$ from the sheet, the total charge at radius $r\pm dr/2 $, with $r \gg x $, contributing to the field is:

$$ \rho = \sigma rdr$$

The transverse component of the field cancel, leaving a longitudinal component:

$$ E_x \propto E\times \frac x r $$

where:

$$ E \propto \frac{\rho}{r^2} \propto \frac {\sigma dr} r$$

So contributions from distant charge falls of as:

$$ dE(r) \propto \frac x {r^2} $$

So you for well behaved charge distributions, you can ignore contributions from $r \gg x $.

If if you get close enough to a surface ($x \ll R_c$) where $R_c$ is the smallest radius of curvature, it looks flat, and

$$ E = c_0 \times \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} $$

For an infinite sheet: $c_0 = \frac 1 2$, and for a conducting sphere: $c_0 = 1$.